# Product ship Licensing for Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, license, legal, commercial

We are in the process of evaluating and deciding which Linux to pick for our product for sale. Currently looking at lubuntu. We would possibly ship lubuntu (in lubuntu desktop mode) installed in our embedded product along with our propriety software. Our Software will make calls to the lubuntu for services. Please advise; what would it take in terms of licenses and what we need to do to satisfy Lubuntu requirements. The quantities are in the thousands. More importantly who should I contact in Lubuntu. When I was asked Canonical I was told to talk to Canonical/Lubuntu. But any Lubuntu leads related to this brings you back to Ubuntu/Canonical. 
If you have any contact information I would greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

For information on how to contact Canonical about:

- **Get involved**
- **Technical assistance**
- **Web feedback**
- **Sales enquiries**
- **Press enquiries**
- **Legal enquiries**
- **Trademark enquiries**
- **Canonical address**

Go here: http://www.ubuntu.com/about/contact-us